# How do i convert a Text with formattings maintained and convert in Markdown Expression form using showdown.js

Tags: javascript, markdown, showdown

I want some solution which can covert  text that may have formatting and convert it into markdown expressions.

for instance :-

## Heading

### Sub-heading

#### Another deeper heading

Paragraphs are separated
by a blank line.

Two spaces at the end of a line leave a
line break.

Text attributes *italic*, *italic*, **bold**, **bold**, `monospace`.

and this text should be converted into the bellow format:-

```
Heading
=======
Sub-heading
-----------
### Another deeper heading

Paragraphs are separated
by a blank line.

Two spaces at the end of a line leave a  
line break.

Text attributes _italic_, *italic*, __bold__, **bold**, `monospace`.
```

Is there any way of doing this using any of the javascript markdown expressions api .

Thank you.

Comment: Plain text has no formatting, which makes it plain. Please clarify what you want to do. From the test of your result, you want to convert *rich* text to plain text / Markdown. If your rich text is HTML, you could try to use https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown

Comment: Hey it worked thank you @pichfl

Comment: it is converting html to markdown expression but Do we have something that does what i want explained above ?

Comment: Converting HTML to Markdown is what you are asking for. If not, then you need to clarify your question. Either way, perhaps [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) will be of use to you as it converts between many different formats.